# Keyclock token service not running

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-cognito, keycloak, auth0

I am trying to experiement with keycloak for authentication and authorization.

I have deployed [keycloak operator](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-operator) on kubernetes and created [example keycloak](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-operator/blob/master/deploy/examples/keycloak/keycloak.yaml) instance. I have created [demo client](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-operator/tree/master/deploy/examples/client) , [realm](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-operator/blob/master/deploy/examples/realm/realm_with_users.yaml) and [user](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-operator/blob/master/deploy/examples/user/user_with_credentials.yaml)

I have been successfully able to port forward and login to admin console.

Now I want to test it using [react-keycloak](https://github.com/panz3r/react-keycloak/tree/master/examples/react-navi) . I have downloaded keycloak.json for my demo client and updated the env file required in react-keycloak example. But it is not working.

Going to  http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/user_realm/  gives me:

```
{
- realm: "user_realm",
- public_key: "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAk/ppy1MdjUBSTdidubb8wwlAKP2Pt4AyfAdQUYA4F1Ecvliir9EC/RZVICfFbQa4Jiekmr8K4Ye7DsXspseOll6ppL8zO3wDVMQNqthLbFHzEzPd+atkA//G6T/pgDKXO45EC0dNuo1Z2O4UWIn1ZewDMM2RlKXg6bcNtYKsWxcfNGqr/SRLkInrGa0yDVfr/anKhPTZhaUkbTrtemucSxGHD3vye5yWSoUbu22TDMmnLKiUOI5TATe/W11Vvbuv6cSEZVx9w1k6nvuHlAwnjrQEmHNS66lL1qtfau7cckM77Lz0TA5P/lYLhFsuGsqFzKyWqG1y1hYcHweYyL48/QIDAQAB",
- token-service: "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/user_realm/protocol/openid-connect",
- account-service: "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/user_realm/account",
- tokens-not-before: 0
}
```

I tried these urls and got the following results:

[image]

[image]

Seems like token service is not enabled. What do I need to do to enable it?
Also, on checking the logs of keycloak pod, I found the following. Not sure if it is related.

[image]

Any tips for me ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Does this page open after redirection from your app?

As far as I can see on the first screenshot in URL :
.../auth?client_id=account&redire.... - instead of account should be 'client-secret'(as I understand from https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-operator/blob/master/deploy/examples/client/client-secret.yaml)